# SwiftUI's new NavigationStack warning about navigationDestination not found but I did provide the type

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I have this minimum repro code:

```
struct ListViewWithNewAPI: View {
  @State var selectedString: String? = nil
  
  var body: some View {
    let details = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    
    NavigationStack {
      List {
        ForEach(details, id: \.self) { detail in
          NavigationLink(detail, value: detail)
        }
      }
      .navigationDestination(item: $selectedString) { detail in
        Text("This is a detailed page for \(detail)")
          .navigationTitle("Detail page")
      }
      .navigationTitle("List page")
    }
  }
}
```

When I tap on the link, I got a warning:

```
A NavigationLink is presenting a value of type “String” but there is no matching navigationDestination declaration visible from the location of the link. The link cannot be activated.
```

But as you can tell, I did provide the `navigationDestination` with correct String type. What is going on here?

Edit: This is my old way of writing it:

```
    List {
      ForEach(details, id: \.self) { detail in
        let destination = Text("This is a detailed page for \(detail)")
          .navigationTitle("Detail page")
        
        NavigationLink(
          detail,
          destination: destination,
          tag: detail,
          selection: $selectedString)
      }
    }
```

This API has been deprecated, but it was working well - I did not have to manually set `$selectedString`.

Comment: You need a `navigationDestination` for a `String` `selectedString` is never set. you can use a `Button` or `onTapGestture` for that

Comment: I edited the question and added my old code using deprecated API. As you can tell, I did not have to manually set the `$selectedString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing the different ways of using `.navigationDestination`.

You can either do it like this:

```swift
.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { detail in
    Text("This is a detailed page for \(detail)")
        .navigationTitle("Detail page")
}
```

or... you can leave the `.navigationDestination` like you have it and change the links to something that updates the state variable `selectedString`, like this:

```swift
ForEach(details, id: \.self) { detail in
    Button(detail) { selectedString = detail }
}
```

---

*EDIT* This works too and gives you the right arrow like before. It's a slightly different way of building the `List`:

```swift
NavigationStack {
    List(details, id: \.self, selection: $selectedString) { detail in
        NavigationLink(detail, value: detail)
    }
    .navigationDestination(item: $selectedString) { detail in
        Text("This is a detailed page for \(detail)")
            .navigationTitle("Detail page")
    }
    .navigationTitle("List page")
}
```

Comment: I don't want to show a `Button`, the navigation link has a right arrow in the row, but the button does not have

Comment: Answer updated with another way to do it. I think this may be the solution you are after.

Comment: it works. thanks!

Comment: I have to say this new API is worse than the old API. In the old API, the destination and the link are together, feels more like descriptive programming. The new API feels more imperative and feels like UIKit.

Comment: Hi Benzy, I tried your solution and it works great for most cases, until I encountered a case where I need `onMove` and `onDelete` functions, which is not found for `List`. Can you take a look at it? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77630002/swiftui-how-to-use-onmove-without-foreach-for-new-navigation-api

Answer (score 0):

You are really close here. The `navigationDestination` you should be using is the `for` variation that allows you to associate it with a type instead of a selected value:

```swift
.navigationDestination(for: String.self, destination: { detail in
    Text("This is a detailed page for \(detail)")
        .navigationTitle("Detail page")
})
```

Comment: What's wrong with the other constructor using `$selectedString`? I need that info for other purposes.

Comment: It looks like Benzy has a solution that can work for you. Nothing is wrong with using the Binding (if you are passing the binding to the next view), but I didn't know that was what your code was intended to do.